# Replace with newline python

Tags: python

I have a string

```
a=">NKMFFALGLLGDGVIGALDTVVSSMGAVGASGLS"
```

I want print a as

```
">
NKMFFALGLLGDGVIGALDTVVSSMGAVGASGLS"
```

I did `a=a.replace(">","> \n")`
but it doesn't work. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: I get the output as '> \n NKMFFALGLLGDGVIGALDTVVSSMGAVGASGLS'

Comment: It works for me. Try using `print`.

Comment: `repr()` escapes the backslashes, there is no problem here.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One thing is the internal representation of the string:

```
>>> a=">NKMFFALGLLGDGVIGALDTVVSSMGAVGASGLS"
>>> a.replace(">","> \n")
'> \nNKMFFALGLLGDGVIGALDTVVSSMGAVGASGLS'
```

another one is how it will be shown on screen:

```
>>> print(a.replace(">","> \n"))
> 
NKMFFALGLLGDGVIGALDTVVSSMGAVGASGLS
```